# Nested if, else if, without brackets

Tags: java

My code used to be:

```
for(int i=1; i<par.length(); i++)
    {
        if( '}'==(par.charAt(i)) )
            if(parStack.pop()!='{')
                return false;

        else if( ')'==(par.charAt(i)) )
                if(parStack.pop()!='(')
                    return false;

        else if( ']'==(par.charAt(i)) )
                if(parStack.pop()!='[')
                    return false;

        else if ( '{'==(par.charAt(i)) || '['==(par.charAt(i)) || '('==(par.charAt(i)))
                parStack.push(par.charAt(i));
    }
```

And it did not work properly, unfortunately. Because of the nature of the error (only worked for {} brackets starting/ending), I realized that the else was redundant (since the method would return false anyways), so I removed it, and the code looked like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<par.length(); i++)
    {
        if( '}'==(par.charAt(i)) )
            if(parStack.pop()!='{')
                return false;

        if( ')'==(par.charAt(i)) )
                if(parStack.pop()!='(')
                    return false;

        if( ']'==(par.charAt(i)) )
                if(parStack.pop()!='[')
                    return false;

        if ( '{'==(par.charAt(i)) || '['==(par.charAt(i)) || '('==(par.charAt(i)))
                parStack.push(par.charAt(i));
    }
```

The code then worked just fine. I was wondering why this error was caused though? I thought brackets would not be necessary for the code above since it was all single statements.

Comment: Describe _it did not work properly_. What did you mean it do to? What did it actually do?

Comment: Well, you didn't change the brackets, did you? what do you think made it work?

Comment: your code is a perfect example of why brackets are never optional. also, you could replace if(A) if(B) with if(A&&B) for much better readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the first else applies to the nearest if statement in this section of the code, i.e. the second if statement.:

```
if( '}'==(par.charAt(i)) )
            if(parStack.pop()!='{')
                return false;

        else if( ')'==(par.charAt(i)) )
                if(parStack.pop()!='(')
                    return false;
```

In order for it to work as expected, you would need to bracket the outer ifs at least:

```
if( '}'==(par.charAt(i)) ) 
{
            if(parStack.pop()!='{')
                return false;
}
        else if( ')'==(par.charAt(i)) )
{
                if(parStack.pop()!='(')
                    return false;
}
....
```

Answer (score 3):

Just because you indented your code that way, it is not going to work as you expect (this is not Python).

In fact, the lines

```
if( '}'==(par.charAt(i)) )
    if(parStack.pop()!='{')
        return false;

else if( ')'==(par.charAt(i)) )
        if(parStack.pop()!='(')
            return false;
...
```

are equivalent to:

```
if( '}'==(par.charAt(i)) )
    if(parStack.pop()!='{')
        return false;
    else if( ')'==(par.charAt(i)) )
        if(parStack.pop()!='(')
            return false;
...
```

which is not what you want.

**What can you do to avoid this?** You could use an IDE with auto-bracketing, like Eclipse. Or just use brackets by yourself:

```
if ('}' == (par.charAt(i))) {
    if (parStack.pop() != '{') {
        return false;
    }
} else if (')' == (par.charAt(i))) {
    if (parStack.pop() != '(') {
        return false;
    }
} ...
```

Comment: is right. If you want to control the flow of execution of the if / else statements, then you need to use the `{` and `}` to specify where the control blocks are.  That's their purpose.